# Way to get list of field references in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

In kubernetes we can easily expose certain params and values through environment variables. Examples of these can be the node IP, the container uid, etc.

Example

```
 - name: POD_ID
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.uid
```

However, I was wondering if there is a way to list the possible references that can be included in the pod. Either in the form of an API reference or dynamically on a pod.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out myself, you can only reference the variables that are also exposed if you `kubectl edit pod <podname>` a pod.

Answer (score 0):

This is called downwardAPI.
Also `variables` or `fields` can exposed using environment variable as you mentioned & also via volume file.

Full documentation is here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/downward-api/#available-fields. Some excerpts are below.

Pod & container **field reference** are available via environment variable using `fieldRef` & `resourceFieldRef`.

- **fieldRef**:
- For pod-level fields.
- For pod-level fields like `status.hostIP`, `metadata.labels`, `metadata.annotations['<KEY>']` etc.
- For full list: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/downward-api/#downwardapi-fieldRef

**resourceFieldRef**

- For container-level fields.
- For fields like `requests.memory`, `limits.cpu`, `requests.hugepages-*` etc
- For full list : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/downward-api/#downwardapi-resourceFieldRef