# Fetch the zone of the master node from a pod in container engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

For a multi zoned, multi cluster setup. Is it possible to dynamically expose or retrieve the zone in which the master node is running, from a pod? Since this is needed to correctly push our metrics to stackdriver, in order to run a [horizontal pod autoscaler](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/tree/master/custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter) based on them.

I can hardcode it in the individual deployments but I would like to avoid that.

I've tried looking in the compute internal metadata endpoint, and in the [reference variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47891326/way-to-get-list-of-field-references-in-kubernetes/47891675#47891675) kubernetes has, but none seem to expose the zone of the master.

Comment: Note that the masters can be regional (i.e. in format `us-central1`) might not  conform with the zone format (i.e. `us-central1-b`) because GKE now has support for multi-zone masters. Therefore for some clusters you might need to look at a different field than zone for @Robert’s answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an unofficial way to determine what zone (or region) the master is running in by parsing the `kube-env` metadata entry on a node. `kube-env` is a key-value store where keys are all uppercase, followed by a colon, which is followed by the value. If you look for the key `ZONE` the value will be the cluster location (e.g. the master zone for multi-zonal clusters with a single zone master or the master region for regional clusters).

Note that this isn't a supported API, so it may disappear in future versions of GKE, but for now it's a simple way to fetch the cluster location from any node.